# CJMCU-3652 resistor dimensioning

Tags: resistors, pcb-design, pcb-assembly, solar-charge-controller

I bought a CJMCU-3652. It is based upon the [LT3652](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3652fe.pdf) from Linear Technologies. In the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3652fe.pdf) on page 15 there is a description on how to calculate the resistors to properly
charge whatever battery you own, I want to charge 4 serially connected [LiPoFe4 batteries](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01BDRIX34/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1). In some [webshops](https://www.mattblatt.com.au/mb/buy/dreamyhome-cjmcu-3652-lt3652-mini-solar-power-2a-battery-charging-module-extension-board-2106214/) in the desciption they state "The charger uses a 3.3V floating voltage feedback reference so a resistor divider can be used to set any desired battery floating voltage of up to 14.4V.". But there is no description on where to put that resistor divider or how to calculate them? Maybe there is already one resistor set so the LT3652 datasheet in only of limited use. As a Schematic-"replacement" I added some photos of the PCB. I hope the quality is good enough. Do you know:

- is there some schematic available for that PCB?
- where to put that resistor?
- what resistance should it have?
- if there is already one resistor set or do I need to set both?

[image: front]

[image: back]